# Insertion Sort Average case giving n instead of n^2 unless in really large array sizes

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, big-o, insertion-sort

im having issue with the average case of insertion sort and testing/implementing it.

As far as I know its meant to be n^2, and when I did around 1 to 200000 arrays filled with random numbers I got exactly that. But now that im doing 20 points and calculating the average to ensure this I get a straight line so O(n)

However when I tried arrays of sizes 100,000, from 100,000 to 1,000,000 I get somewhat of a curved, quadratic line

```
public static void averageCase() {
    for (int x = 10000; x <= 30000; x += 1000) {
        int[] averageArray = randomArray(x);
        float average = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
            float startTime = System.nanoTime();
            insertionSort(averageArray, averageArray.length);
            float estimateTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            average += estimateTime;
        }
        System.out.println(average/100000);
    }
}

public static int[] randomArray(int n) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] randomArray = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
        randomArray[i] = random.nextInt(1000);
    }
    return randomArray;
}
```

results are:

16504.586

18559.795

20468.203

22083.01

23530.045

25186.795

27179.09

28793.896

30534.533

32149.34

33869.004

35819.355

37539.02

39216.742

40978.35

42551.215

44186.992

46158.316

47584.38

49660.56

51191.48

Comment: Yes, and?  O(n^2) refers to long term behavior, it can look different for small n.

Comment: To agree with Louis, O, theta, and omega time only refer to the asymptotic bounds. Try with inputs much closer to infinity. And then rule out all possible runtime testing issues like hidden behaviors such as caching as well as anything else that makes physical computers different from theoretical ones. And then you might see results matching your expectations.

Comment: I was just making sure/confirming to be honest, I spent so much time thinking theres something wrong with my method of implementation because I already tried out and confirmed best and worst case, and wasn't sure why I couldnt get appropriate measurements.

Comment: I think the problem isn't that n isn't large enough, it's that your code isn't measuring what you think it's measuring. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remember O(n^2) signals your upper bound. Insertion sort has a linear lower bound. Try with larger numbers and a bunch of times.

Answer (score 0):

In your inner loop, you're repeatedly sorting the same array, rather than randomizing it each time.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
    float startTime = System.nanoTime();
    insertionSort(averageArray, averageArray.length);
    float estimateTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    average += estimateTime;
}
```

Since insertion sort runs in linear time on already sorted input, you're measuring 1/100000 of a quadratic time algorithm, and 99999/100000 of a linear time algorithm.

And that's why your timings are much flatter than you expect.